# Erro ao importar projeto no eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Estou tentando importar um projeto que tenho salvo. Porém, quando importo, o arquivo `style.xml`, dá erro nessa linha:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Com a mensagem:

> retrieving parent for item

Já adicionei ao projeto a biblioteca `appcompat v7` como manda o site oficial, mas o erro do projeto não some.

Answer (score 1):

Não costumo desenvolver para Android, mas vou tentar ajudar.

Primeramente notei que o atributo `parent` do seu código não tem o prefixo `@style`. Veja como está na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

```xml
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Se isso não funcionar verifique se realmente executou os passos abaixo para adicionar a biblioteca `appcompat`, como sugerido [numa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support):

1. Menu `File > Import`
2. Procure por `android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7`
3. Escolha `appcompat`
4. Menu `Project > properties > Android`
5. Na seção `library`, clique em `Add`
6. Escolha `appCompat`

Se ainda não funcionar, conforme sugerido em [outra resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295018/error-error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-give), verifique se a versão da API está pelo menos no level 11 e se os `import`s estão corretos. De acordo com a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), os pacotes mudam antes e depois do level 11.

Se mais uma vez não funcionar, a última fonte também sugere alterar o *build target* do projeto para pelo menos a versão `4.0.3` nas configurações do seu projeto em `Properties > Android`.

Comment: Ja tentei todas as opções e nada, o projeto foi criado para o 2.2, inclusive ja criei outro projeto porque o eclipse ja cria automatico o projeto appcompat v7, mas ele nao tira o erro do projeto. Não tem como recuperar esse projeto mesmo?

Comment: @WarLock Seria preciso olhar todas as configurações do projeto para verificar a origem do problema. Você pode fazer isso, se quiser. Primeiro configure o Eclipse para exibir os arquivos de configuração do projeto (`*. resources`). Você pode ver como fazer isso [neste link](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-27.htm). Faça isso para o projeto que funciona e com o que não funciona, então poderá olhar as configurações e analisar qual a diferença. Comece pelo `.project`, depois o `.classpath` e finalmente todos da pasta ``.settings`.